# Properties of Fourier transform for finite measure

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

We know that if $f\in L^p, ~1\leq p \leq 2$ then $\hat{f}\in L^q$ such that $1/p +1/q=1.$

Now let us assume that $\mu$ is a finite measure. Then for $f\in L^p(d\mu)$ for any $1\leq p \leq \infty, $ Fourier transform of $f$ defined by,
$$\hat{f}(y)=\int_\mathbb{R} f(x)e^{-ixy} d\mu(x),$$
is well defined.

1)Is it true that $\hat{f}\in L^q(d\mu)$ such that $1/p +1/q=1$ for $1\leq p \leq 2?$

2)Is it true that $\hat{f}\in L^q(d\mu)$ such that $1/p +1/q=1$ for $1\leq p \leq \infty?$

Edit: I tried the following. Is it correct?

[image]

Comment: Why is the FT well defined? What is the connection between Lebesgue measure and $\mu$?

Comment: With respect to that measure $\mu$

Comment: I edited the question accordingly

Comment: It looks like you are missing the estimate of $L^2$ to $L^2$. If you prove that, then you can use interpolation to get the intermediate values.

Comment: Why I can't use interpolation between 1 and \infty ?